# Icon Color in lightning badge changed to grey after winter 24 upgrade

Tags: lightning-web-components, icon, winter24, lightning-icon

My Icon color which is in a badge has changed to grey after salesforce winter 24 upgrade, earlier it worked with the color which I specified .I have tried many things but none of them worked, Kindly help

Here is my HTML code

```html
<li class="dot">
    <lightning-badge label={status} class={DAstatusclass} icon-name={DAstatusicon} ></lightning-badge>
</li>
<li>
    <lightning-badge label="Credit" class={creditclass} icon-name={crediticon} color="white"></lightning-badge>
</li>
```

JS code

```js
get DAstatusclass(){
    switch (this.status) {
        case 'Active':
            return 'cusBadge txtUcase badgeGreen white-icon';
        case 'Inactive':
            return 'cusBadge txtUcase badgeRed white-icon';
        default:
            return 'cusBadge txtUcase badgeOrange white-icon';
    }}
```

CSS

```css
.txtUcase { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cusBadge {
    padding: 1px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: left;
}
.badgeGreen {
    background:#009883;
    color:#fff!important;
}
.badgeGreen .slds-badge__icon {
    color:#fff!important;
}
.white-icon {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default:#ffffff!important;
}
```

Comment: Probably related to the internal updates being made to base components as part of the preparation for using a real shadow DOM. Fundamentally you need to use the mechanisms Salesforce provides, such as [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) or properties on the components when wanting to control their appearance. The whole point with shadow DOM is that it prevents the rendering of a component being impacted by style sheets applied in a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the encapsulation provided by [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html)
CSS styles defined in a parent component don't leak into a child component. This means that every rule defined in you CSS file only apply to the element owned by your own component. They cannot change the style of a standard component even if you put `!important`.

The only way to customize standard component styling is via [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/), as you did with the `white-icon` class. Please note that `--sds-*` tokens are deprecated, you should use `--slds-*` ones.

Looking at [Badge Blueprint page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/badges/#Styling-Hooks-Overview), you can find the CSS custom properties you need, like:

- `--slds-c-badge-color-background`
- `--slds-c-badge-text-color`
- `--slds-c-badge-icon-color-foreground`
- `--slds-c-badge-radius-border`

So you should change your CSS file to:

```css
.txtUcase { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cusBadge {
    padding: 1px 6px;
    --slds-c-badge-radius-border: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: left;
}

.badgeGreen {
    --slds-c-badge-color-background: #009883;
    --slds-c-badge-text-color: #fff;
}

.white-icon {
    --slds-c-badge-icon-color-foreground: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me a lot